# How to be sure that a request is executed by browser and not by a script that use curl

Tags: javascript, browser, fraud-prevention, botnet

By asking this question I assume that requests from the browser to backend server are catchable by network console and possible to reproduce simply by a "Copy as curl".

Let's say I want to collect a dummy value from my browser to analyse it from my backend system, for example:

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

How can I be sure that `window.devicePixelRatio` is the user's real one? I mean, a malicious user can block the request sent to the backend and craft his own request with a simple `curl`.

Is it technically possible to make this impossible or really difficult for malicious users? Is there some pattern to do this?

Comment: No, it is not technically possible to ensure that you are getting information from a "real" web browser.